# como puedo arreglo este error en unity c# y/o en visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity2d

soy nuevo en unity y en c# y en este lugar, estoy creando un juego con varios amigos y yo tengo un problema con una parte, que sería: "UnassignedReferenceException: The variable controladorSuelo of movimientojugador has not been assigned"

el código completo seria este

```
{
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
[Header("movimiento")]
private float movimientohorizontal = 0f;
[SerializeField] private float velocidaddemovimiento;
[SerializeField] private float suavizadodemovimiento;
private Vector3 velocidad = Vector3.zero;
private bool mirandoderecha = true;

[Header("salto")]
[SerializeField] private float fuerzaDeSalto;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask queEsSuelo;
[SerializeField] private Transform controladorSuelo;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 dimensionescaja;
[SerializeField] private bool enSuelo;
private bool Salto = false;


private void Start()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    movimientohorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * velocidaddemovimiento;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("jump"))
    {
        Salto = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    enSuelo = Physics2D.OverlapBox(controladorSuelo.position, dimensionescaja, 0f, queEsSuelo);

    //mover
    mover(movimientohorizontal * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Salto);
    Salto = false;
}
private void mover(float mover, bool saltar)
{

    Vector3 velocidadobjetivo = new Vector2(mover, rb2D.velocity.y);
    rb2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(rb2D.velocity, velocidadobjetivo, ref velocidad, suavizadodemovimiento);
    if (mover > 0 && !mirandoderecha)
    {
        //girar
        girar();
    }
    else if (mover < 0 && mirandoderecha)
    {
        //girar
        girar();
    }
    if(enSuelo && saltar)
    {
        enSuelo = false;
        rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0F, fuerzaDeSalto));
    }
}
private void girar()
{
    mirandoderecha = !mirandoderecha;
    Vector3 escala = transform.localScale;
    escala.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = escala;
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(controladorSuelo.position, dimensionescaja);
}
```

}

además ya no me deja moverme con el A y D y menos saltar y no sé qué tengo que hacer para poder volver a moverme y saltar, cualquier cosa que necesiten para que puedan ayudarme avísenme, muchas gracias

Comment: Dice que debes asignar la variable `controladorSuelo`. No hay mucho misterio. Solo interpretar los errores.

Comment: tengo que recalcar que soy nuevo? COMO asigno la variable o a donde

Comment: Puedes asignarla desde el inspector o desde el mismo script porque tiene `[SerializeField]`. Ya que al ser privada no sé puede acceder desde otras clases

Comment: ya pude asignarla y no me aparece ningún error, pero no me salta, me fije bien que sea el espacio y hasta use layer y no salta

Comment: Posiblemente la fuerza del salto sea muy débil.

Comment: lo puse en 90000 para probar y nada

Comment: Prueba a poner un Debug.Log() en el if a ver si se está ejecutando al menos. Si la conversación va a ser extensa, mejor vayamos al [chat].